# What are the conditions when a variable can be both dynamically bound and cause a void-variable issue?

Tags: variables

I get:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable implicit-layout-active)
```

When using a variable declared as dynamically bound:

```
(void-variable implicit-layout-active)
```

I thought I cannot get `void-variable` issue for declared dynamically bound variables. Note that I do not use `makunbound`. But I do use `lexical-binding: t` for the module in question. What can this be?

More info here: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/854

Comment: Having looked at `haskell-indentation.el`, I'd say that the whole thing is flawed.  The use of unprefixed dynamic variables is a major concern, and enabling `lexical-scoping` for a file that's supposed to work with Emacs 23 (according to some comments) is another, the more since there are places where the module explicitly works around the lack of lexical binding—which leads the whole purposes of `lexical-binding: t` ad absurdum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the misconception that a dynamic (special) variable cannot be unbound, and the misconception that the user had given the variable a binding.

Comment: Well it's a misconception we don't share but that doesn't mean others don't.

Comment: @Drew I respectfully disagree.  It's a valid question for this site, in my opinion, even if it's based on a misconception.

Comment: @lunaryorn: this module is undergoing renovation, hence the question. Emacs 24 support will be dropped, whole thing will not use any dynamic binding, but explicit state.

Comment: Emacs 23 that is.

Comment: I understand. That's why we have *votes* about closing. You might be right that this will help others more than confuse them. I'm not convinced of that so far, but that's unlikely to be important, unless several other people vote to close also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A special—a dynamically bound variable that is—variable can surely be void.  From [Void Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html) (emphasis mine):

> We say that a variable is void if its symbol has an **unassigned** value cell (see Symbol Components).
>
> Under Emacs Lisp’s default dynamic scoping rule (see Variable Scoping), the value cell stores the variable’s current (local or global) value. **Note that an unassigned value cell is not the same as having nil in the value cell**. The symbol nil is a Lisp object and can be the value of a variable, just as any other object can be; but it is still a value. If a variable is void, trying to evaluate the variable signals a void-variable error, instead of returning a value.

In other words, the scoping rules of a variable are *unrelated* to whether it is actually bound or not.  `(defvar implicit-layout-active)` declares the variable special, but it does *not* assign a value.  The variable is still void.  See for yourself:

```
ELISP> (defvar implicit-layout-active)
implicit-layout-active
ELISP> (special-variable-p 'implicit-layout-active)
t
ELISP> (boundp 'implicit-layout-active)
nil
ELISP> implicit-layout-active
*** Eval error ***  Symbol’s value as variable is void: implicit-layout-active
```

You need to assign a value, either in the declaration or later, to make a variable special *and* bound, i.e. non-void. Your code apparently does not do that.

Specifically, you'd need to use `(defvar implicit-layout-active nil)`. But at this point you should **definitely use prefixed names**.  Declaring unprefixed global variables is *very bad* style, and arguably somewhat rude towards other packages.  And generally, `haskell-indentation.el` is not particularly friendly in this regard: It declares over a dozen of these.  Please, please, please, don't do that.  Sooner or later other Emacs package developers are going to hate you for this.

Comment: +1 I'm wondering whether I should delete my answer because we have three correct answers here :-)

Comment: No no, we have to keep the answers per question count up :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are *not* binding the variable dynamically. *Edit: A sorry, I see now that you actually have declared the variable to be dynamically bound. But I am keeping the part of the answer which assumes otherwise anyway, as it might help others.*

When `lexical-binding` is set to `t`, then `let`, and other forms, bind variables lexically by default - that's what that setting does.

However `let` can bind some variables lexically and others dynamically. What it should do for a particular variable, it figures out by checking whether the variable has been defined, or at least declared to be defined. So add this:

```
(defvar implicit-layout-active nil)
```

You most certainly also want to add a package prefix to that symbol and maybe add a doc-string explaining that the variable is only intended to be let-bound.

If you already have such a definition, but get the above error anyway, then that is probably because you use the variable *before* defining it. The order might also be wrong due to the use of outdated `*.elc` files.

Instead of the above you have used:

```
(defvar implicit-layout-active)
```

I.e. you are declaring that the variable is defined, without actually making sure that there always is a binding. When you now evaluate some code which tries to get the value of the variable without it actually being bound dynamically, well then it is void.

Comment: Variable is defined in global scope, it is used by calling functions from that module, that is *after* it has been loaded. `(defvar implicit-layout-active nil)` vs `(defvar implicit-layout-active)` does not make a difference, both fail with the same error described in questions.

Comment: Strange... Well let's see what others can come up with. ;-)

Comment: @GracjanPolak You've made something wrong then.  No offense meant, but there _is_ a difference between these two forms:  The former binds, the latter does _not_.  In other words, with the former, `boundp` is non-nil, i.e. the variable is not void, whereas with the latter `boundp` is nil, meaning that the variable is in fact void.

Comment: @tarsius +1, you're actually right:  The OP does not bind the variable dynamically, they just declared it as a special, i.e. dynamically bound, variable.

Comment: @lunaryorn It appears you have actually looked at the code in question to make sure it is always let-bound when an attempt to get its value is made. Unlike me I have to admit. You'll get an upvote from me just for that, and since I cannot upvote more than once you get just one anyway :-)

Comment: @tarsius: I retract my comment about `(defvar x)` being same as `(defvar x nil)`. What confused me was that I got errors in both cases, but different errors.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought I cannot get void-variable issue for declared dynamically bound
>   variables.

Your assumption is wrong. Dynamically bound (or “special” in other Lisps)
variables can be unbound. In fact if you declare it like (taken from
`haskell-indentation.el`):

```el
(defvar implicit-layout-active) ;; is "off-side" rule active?
```

You are declaring variable `implicit-layout-active` without setting its
value. We can read about it in doc-string:

> defvar is a special form in ‘C source code’.
>
> (defvar SYMBOL &optional INITVALUE DOCSTRING)
>
> …
>
> The optional argument INITVALUE is evaluated, and used to set SYMBOL, only
>   if SYMBOL's value is void.  If SYMBOL is buffer-local, its default value
>   is what is set; buffer-local values are not affected.  **If INITVALUE is
>   missing, SYMBOL's value is not set.**

This answers your question: you've defined a dynamic variable and have not
set its value. Obviously your code doesn't `let` bind it in some case and
thus you get the error.

---

As for your comment that `(defvar implicit-layout-active)` is the same as
`(defvar implicit-layout-active nil)` — you should check better. A few
things to consider:

1. When your test suite evaluates `(require 'haskell-indentation)` which
   module does it load: where you supply default value or “older” byte
   compiled version installed via package manager?
2. Also note that `defvar` only sets value if variable is currently unbound
   (this is not actual issue in your case, just a word of caution).

Having said all this I can evaluate

```el
(defvar implicit-layout-active nil)
```

and the dynamic variable is bound:

```el
(boundp implicit-layout-active) ⇒ t
```

Now if I run your test case I get:

```el
F haskell-indentation-check-23
    should not fail when seeing comments
    (ert-test-failed
     ((should
       (equal
        (cons
         (list ... ...)
         (haskell-indentation-find-indentations))
        current))
      :form
      (equal
       ((3 2))
       ((3 2)
        0))
      :value nil :explanation
      (proper-lists-of-different-length 1 2
                                        ((3 2))
                                        ((3 2)
                                         0)
                                        first-mismatch-at 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for thorough help. I accepted the answer by lunaryorn because it is more general, but you should receive a badge for actually running the code in question :)